# Что значит путь "\\\\.\\NTICE"?

Tags: winapi, path, пути

Объясните, что означает этот путь:

```
 "\\\\.\\NTICE"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полностью подпрограмма для открытия файла:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А откуда у вас это? И к исходникам доступа нет?

Comment: Нет, это keygen

Comment: Кстати, без этой манипуляции не происходит проверка ключа

Comment: Опишите ситуацию нормально плиз. По таким обрывкам сложно что-то понять.

Comment: Это проверка на наличие запущенного отладчика SoftICE. Тут делается попытка открыть файл (устройство) `"\\\\.\\NTICE"` через `CreateFile`. Если возвращается что-нибудь, отличное от -1 (`INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`), то SoftICE запущен. Если отладчик запущен, то работа вашей программы завершается.

Comment: @Embedder спасибо, напишите ответом

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это проверка на наличие запущенного отладчика SoftICE. Тут делается попытка открыть файл (устройство) `"\\.\NTICE"` через `CreateFile`. Если возвращается что-нибудь, отличное от -1 (`INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`), то SoftICE запущен. Если отладчик запущен, то работа вашей программы завершается.

Answer (score 5):

Путь записан в C-нотации, если убрать экранирующие слэши, останется `\\.\NTICE` и обозначает путь к устройству NTICE (см. [английскую документацию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx), раздел Win32 Device Namespaces).

Скорее всего, это устройство, которое создаётся определённым отладчиком ядра (типа SoftICE), и код проверяет наличие такого отладчика по наличию этого пути.